# Calculating SPL in octaves from .wav file recorded with microphone in Python

Tags: amplifier, analog, gain, microphone

I made a recording of my environment with a microphone with the following specs: [image]

The recording has a sample rate of 44.1 kHz and a bit depth of 16. I use:

y, sr = librosa.load(latest_file, sr = 44100)

to load the .wav file and with numpy I looked at the max and min value in the array. these are the results:

[image]

The absolute max value I got was -1 to 1 (Clapping really hard near the microphone), so i think that the microphone maps from -1 volt to 1 volt?

decided to measure the output when measuring random ambient sound to get an idea of the order of magnitude. I measured around 60 mV at the mic module (see picture below) and ~120 mV ish at the output of the whole thing. [image]

The mic is powered by USB, this is the module it comes with: [image]

Now comes the part where I most likely make a mistake. After loading in the file I tried to convert the output of the mic, so the data wich I think is voltage, to dB SPL with the following formula:

GAIN = 2

SENSITIVITY = 0.02 V (-34 dB)

ATH = 0.00002

20*log10(((y/GAIN)/SENSITIVTY)/ATH)

[image]

this obviously gave an error because you cant take the log of negative numbers. So now I first do the fourier transform and then I calculate the dB SPL wich gives the following results:

[image]

To get the octaves I simply cut the array with the corresponding frequencies. To get the dB SPL in each octave I simply take the mean of all the calculated dB SPL values in the octave (this is most likely wrong, please enlighten me haha).

I measured the ambient sound with a dB meter (it had A weighting) and found ~34 dB on low setting and ~50 dB on high setting. This is way lower than what I found! I think the gain I use is the main issue so my quetion is: How do I measure/find the gain of this microphone?

Other things I'm struggling with:

- I read most mics have outputs above 0, between 2 and 5 volts for example, can I manipulate my .wav file to also map my waveform between those values? Reason for this is because then its possible to convert the values to dB SPL before the fourier transform.
- Why do I measure ~60 mV at the output of the electret module when recording ambient sound when the sensitivity of the thing is -34 dB? The voltage I measured seems WAY too high.
- Is a high dB SPL reading in the higher octaves normal?
- Is the formula I'm using correct?

Hope to get some help, if in need of more info let me know. Cheers!

Comment: The microphone does map anything. If you had a 16-bit PCM it is clear that numpy mapped the 16 bit range to float between -1 and +1. They are numbers, not volts. And if you don't know which dB SPL maps to which Volts or how Volts map to numbers, you need to figure it out, so you can convert the numbers back to dB SPL if that is what you want to do.

Comment: @Justme Thanks a ton, this was actually it.  Turns out I had zero idea what the output of my mic actually was. Measured the output with an oscilloscope while gathering data and found that the max value of my array was 1.8 times bigger than the measured Vp.